# AnsiColor plugin within Jenkins Pipeline Shared Library - Usage Issue

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, ansi-colors

I defined a quick logger in my pipeline to test the colored logs with AnsiColor plugin.

It works like a charm.

```
def logger(String str, String level)
{
   if (level == "ALERT")
   {
        ansiColor('xterm')
        {
            echo '\033[32m' + str // Green
        }
   }
   else if (level == "BOLD")
   {
        ansiColor('xterm')
        {
           echo '\033[1;31m' + str // Green
        }
   }
}
```

I call it then

```
logger("CHECK THIS ALERT","ALERT")
```

and it prints:

[image]

Now the problem is that I want to move this method in a class in our shared libraries (we already have some other share libs working with no issues)

But when I move the method under the shared lib class the below issue:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.pipeline.Logger.ansiColor() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [xterm, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@a2e9a55]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
```

I think this is an issue of visibility so that the shared Library does not have visibility of the ansiColor() method, but I'm not sure how to import it, with the DSL plugin we deal with those issues through the delegate usage, but as far I know they are not usable within the pipelines.

Comment: The function invocation would change to `<global_var>.logger` once placed in the shared library. Also you would indeed likely need to import the `ansicolor` within the global var or package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint Matt, I never used global vars within shared libraries, and at the moment it finding just quite unclear examples, can you give me few more details or maybe a link or a good example?

Comment: I would check here for the full `import` path statement: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansicolor-plugin

Comment: I'm unable to make it work and cannot find information anywhere, that package cannot be imported, i can import it from org.jenkinsci.plugins but I can't find information anywhere about how to use those API so I don't know how to call the ansicolor('xterm') method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar class that I use in my shared libraries. I think that what you're missing is the "pipeline" object. Your class should look like:

```
class MyLogger implements Serializable {

    static void logger(Script pipelineScript, String str, String level){
        if (level == "ALERT"){
           pipelineScript.ansiColor('xterm'){
              pipelineScript.echo '\033[32m' + str // Green
           }
        }
        else if (level == "BOLD"){
            pipelineScript.ansiColor('xterm'){
            pipelineScript.echo '\033[1;31m' + str // Green
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Then call it from you Jenkinsfile:

```
Mylogger.logger(this, "CHECK THIS ALERT","ALERT")
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
class MyLogger implements Serializable {

    static void printError(Script script, String message) {
        script.echo "\u001B[1;31m [ERROR] ${message} \u001B[0m"
    }


    static void printInfo(Script script, String message) {
        script.echo "\u001B[1;34m [INFO] ${message} \u001B[0m"
    }

    static void printWarn(Script script, String message) {
        script.echo "\u001B[1;33m [INFO] ${message} \u001B[0m"
    }

}
```

And then the usage from the Jenkinsfile is:

```
ConsoleLogger.printInfo(this,"This is an info")
ConsoleLogger.printWarn(this,"This is a warning")
ConsoleLogger.printError(this,"This is an error")
```